# Facebook FQL multiquery vs batch requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am developing a Facebook app and I need to fetch a lot of data from users. I am concerned about limits Facebook has. I can't send queries one by one, I would soon get error 4 "API Too Many Calls". So I am wondering what is a better approach, if grouping queries into multiquery or sending them in batch. Btw I will have to use multiqueries in batch request. So here is an example :)

Suppose that USER_A and USER_B are friends so I can access them both with 1 access token.

```
multiquery for USER_A:
"Q0":"SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=<USER_A>",
"Q1":"SELECT id FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #Q0)"

multiquery for USER_B
"Q2":"SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=<USER_B>",
"Q3":"SELECT id FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #Q2)"
```

So what is better approach, grouping these 2 multiqueries into 1 bigger multiquery or putting them into a batch request? In which case will Facebook count it as 1 API call? Facebook has some limit like 100M API calls per day. So if I send my 2 multiqueries in batch / bigger multiquery, will facebook count it as 1 API call?

EDIT: by batch request i mean this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

I am not asking if I should use FQL or Graph API, I want to know if there is a difference between sending multiqueries in batch and sending them as 1 bigger multiquery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do everything with one `access_token`, in my experience, a large FQL multiquery returns the results more quickly than a batch request.

Also, looking at your example query, you could cut the number of queries down by combining these:

```
'User_A_Comments': 
  "SELECT id, post_id FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM 
  (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=<USER_A>) )"
```

The advantage that a batch request would give you is you could use multiple access tokens to get this information in one shot.

Comment: thx for pointing out that i can use multiple access tokens with batch request :)